# How can I start OpenVPN server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

I have a problem with openvpn server on Ubuntu

After sudo systemctl I got that error
"Job for openvpn@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn@server.service" for details."

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Somebody know how can I fix it?

Comment: 'openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --verb 3' -what does the command return? And 'journalctl -xeu openvpn@server.service'